# Magento URL parameters

Tags: magento-1.9, url, controllers, parameter

Is there a way that I can hide URL parameters identifiers?

from: domain.com/frontname/param1/x/param2/y/param3/z

to:  domain.com/frontname/x/y/z

Comment: you need this for custom extension or magento default?